# How to use Python to search through a json file of list of dictionaries regex or Whoosh

Tags: python, json, whoosh

I scraped several e-commerce websites (more than 5) and the data is stored in a large json file as a **list of dictionaries**, like this:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.amazon.com/category/product_1", 
  "price": 539, 
  "product_code": ["x123"], 
  "page_title": "Smartphone Samsung Galaxy S7", 
  "h1": "Smartphone Samsung Galaxy S7, 2.3GHz / 1.6GHz,QHD Super AMOLED"
 }
```

The list is composed of more than 11k dictionaries.

Given that all the data is standardized, how can I search through it for best results?

Is it better to **use Regex** or to index the json file with something like **Whoosh**?

For example, when somebody is looking for ***galaxy s7 case*** I want to return the relevant data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Small nitpick:  Those are JSON "objects", not "dictionaries".  They'll turn into dictionaries when you do `json.loads(...)`.

As for your question - try it!  You can cut down the list to, say, 10,000 items, then test each implementation, regex, list comprehension, Whoosh, haystack, etc., and see how fast they are, with the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module.

As what you're trying to do is a search over a large amount of products, I'd suggest looking into a search engine.  Some good ones I've used are [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [xapian](https://xapian.org/), though if you're already familiar with Whoosh, it certainly sounds like the best option you proposed.

Comment: Sorry, yes they are JSON objects.